# How to get a Python Tkinter Applet to Web Page

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote an applet in Python using the Tkinter library. I finished writing the applet but now I want to make it public on my website. Does anyone know a way to get the python script to work on my website? I don't want it to have to be something that needs to be downloaded, but can just run in the browser if possible. 
Thanks!

Comment: isn't tkinter a GUI library? how did you create a web applet with it???

Comment: @Mintaka: Tkinter apps run on the desktop, not in the web.  You created an application - not an applet.

Comment: Ah... Hmm. Would it be possible to wrap it in Jython somehow to make it a Java applet using the code I wrote?

Comment: A Java applet still has to be downloaded, though it runs in the browser.

Answer (score 8):

**What you ask is not possible**. Several years ago there was a [Tcl/Tk browser plugin](http://www.tcl.tk/software/plugin/), but the last time anyone touched that sourceforge project was back in 2006. I seriously doubt it could be made to work with tkinter. For that matter, I doubt it works for tcl/tk either. Browsers have advanced quite a bit since then.

And no, getting it to work in jython so you can run it via a java plugin won't help. Tkinter works by working directly with a tcl/tk interpreter. The tcl/tk interpreter won't run in the JVM.