# Hello! I wanted to know how we can convert a GUI application(Tkinter) into a link.

Tags: python-3.x

Like I have a made an aplication in GUI python.But I want t to be in form of a link so that user on clicking that link opens the application

Comment: You need to give a lot more explanation of what you are actually trying to do if you want support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to accomplish is to have a link from a web page open a desktop application on Windows, you should see this question: [Launch application from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/launch-application-from-a-browser)

Comment: i have made an application in simple GUI (Tkinter python). Now I wanted it to be accessible to other people in form of a link . So what changes i have to make in my application code.

Comment: Then there's no (easy) way to do that ([see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017538/how-to-get-a-python-tkinter-applet-to-web-page)). You'll have to rewrite the GUI using a web framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).